# What are the requirements of a transaction being included in a block?

Tags: protocol, block, transaction-verification, transaction-selection

What are the requirements of a transaction being included in a block? How does a miner verify that a transaction meets such requirements?

Answer (score 1):

From the Bitcoin wiki (as-of March 19, 2013):

> Transactions are cryptographically signed records that reassign
>   ownership of Bitcoins to new addresses. Transactions have inputs -
>   records which reference the funds from other previous transactions -
>   and outputs - records which determine the new owner of the transferred
>   Bitcoins, and which will be referenced as inputs in future
>   transactions as those funds are respent.
>
> Each input must have a
>   cryptographic digital signature that unlocks the funds from the prior
>   transaction. Only the person possessing the appropriate private key is
>   able to create a satisfactory signature; this in effect ensures that
>   funds can only be spent by their owners.
>
> Each output determines which
>   Bitcoin address (or other criteria, see Scripting) is the recipient of
>   the funds.
>
> In a transaction, the sum of all inputs must be equal to or
>   greater than the sum of all outputs. If the inputs exceed the outputs,
>   the difference is considered a transaction fee, and is redeemable by
>   whoever first includes the transaction into the block chain.
>
> A special
>   kind of transaction, called a coinbase transaction, has no inputs. It
>   is created by miners, and there is one coinbase transaction per block.
>   Because each block comes with a reward of newly created Bitcoins (e.g.
>   50 BTC for the first 210,000 blocks), the first transaction of a block
>   is, with few exceptions, the transaction that grants those coins to
>   their recipient (the miner). In addition to the newly created
>   Bitcoins, the coinbase transaction is also used for assigning the
>   recipient of any transaction fees that were paid within the other
>   transactions being included in the same block. The coinbase
>   transaction can assign the entire reward to a single Bitcoin address,
>   or split it in portions among multiple addresses, just like any other
>   transaction. Coinbase transactions always contain outputs totaling the
>   sum of the block reward plus all transaction fees collected from the
>   other transactions in the same block.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Transaction_Verification

Comment: Yeah, I read that. Not at all what I meant. I mean, how does a client/node do what is described in that article? How can I improve the question?

Comment: If you read C++, it is documented best in the bitcoin/bitcoin project on GitHub.  I know you are probably looking for a technical paper.  The source code is where that exists for now.

Comment: Or PicoCoin shows it fairly well, in C: https://github.com/jgarzik/picocoin

Comment: Or the most simplified pseudocode:

If UTXO is not yet spent, eligible for including in block.
If space in block, include eligible transactions.